# Call a function from file based on command line arguments dynamically in rust

Tags: rust, dynamic, runtime, dynamic-dispatch

This is my project structure

```
project/
├── Cargo.toml
├── src/
│   ├── main.rs
│   └── problems/
│       ├── file1.rs
│       ├── file2.rs
│       ├── ...
│       └── fileN.rs
```

Each of the `fileN.rs` files contain the same `solve()` function in it.

What I am trying to do is:

when I give command line arguments like `cargo run -- 1`, then the `main.rs`  file should run
`problems::file1::solve(); // have some info to print`

when I give command line arguments like `cargo run -- 2`, then the `main.rs`  file should run
`problems::file2::solve(); // have some info to print`

I tried using **match statement** with all the input numbers and these numbers pointing to the respective functions. but as the number of files in `problems` folder increases, the code becomes lengthy and unnecessary repetitive.

Is there a way to dynamically do this?

Comment: My advice: just use a `match`. Yes, it is possible to be clever with macros and so, but the code will be less readable and I don't think it'll be less to type.

Comment: I tried using match and it was working fine and I am currently using match statement, but I am looking for a dynamic way to do this.

Comment: There isn't a fully dynamic way (like in Python or JavaScript), because Rust is a static language. You can do it with macros, but it won't be cleaner IMHO.

Comment: Do you have any examples or resources that I can refer to for this case?

Comment: You can for example wrap the `mod` declarations in a macro that will generate a function to `match`.

Comment: There are solutions from other users doing similar things that were done via procedural macros or build scripts ([here](/q/74858663/2189130) and [here](/q/74642159/2189130)) though I would not encourage this route personally.